# jQuery.dynatree.js - JS Error in IE 8, Unknown Runtime Error Line 320 char 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, runtime-error, dynatree

My dynatree works fine in Firefox.
In internet explorer 8 it gives me an unknown runtime error.

What can I do?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to address your question.  Please include some detail about what you are trying to do, and at least a little source code.  Particularly vital would be the code at line 320.  Ideally, include a complete repro of your problem at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bug, I had the same problem.

Use the jquery html function to pass in the `_getInnerHtml()`

```
var span = $(this.span);
span.html(this._getInnerHtml());
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [listed issues](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/list) for the dynatree project on googlecode for possible workarounds. Or [file a new issue](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/entry) after checking you have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.dynatree.js tested with IE 6+, FF, Safari and Chrome. 
Probably your code contains error